# Change text size of active or inactive tab in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tablayout, text-size

I need to have different text size of active and inactive tabs, but I've found out only how to change the text size for all tabs like this

```
<style name="TextTabLayout" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
</style>
```

but is there any way to set different text size for active and inactive tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can set tab size in onTabSelected().
like this

```
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                ((TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text1)).setTextSize(16);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                ((TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text1)).setTextSize(13);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```